# How can I run an existing GitHub Action as a non-root user?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, rootless

In our project, we're using the [super-linter](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/super-linter) to lint our code. The problem is that it's based on a docker container that runs as root. Files written to the mounted volumes are written as root, and based on that we have trouble with e.g. cached files etc. I would love to run the action as the non-root user on my self-hosted runner, but do not know how to do that or if it's even possible. In the [GitHub Actions Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepswithargs), I've found how to add arguments, but it seems I can't use that to pass a `--user <myUser>` to the `docker run` command. I can't use a `USER <myUser>` inside the dockerfile either since I'm taking the existing action and can't change the dockerfile.

Any idea how to run an existing GitHub Action as a non-root user?

Comment: Probable more relevant to rise an issue in the Superlinter project. https://github.com/super-linter/super-linter/issues

Comment: @jessehouwing while this is a good idea, it's a general issue with a lot of actions, so would be nice to have a solution to that independent of the action itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue when using containers on long-lived self-hosted runners, as well as a big reason not to use these runners, but switch to ephemeral runners (with other security concerns for long-lived runners).

[But for this issue: you can use the container configuration for a self-hosted runner to have a custom cleanup step.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/customizing-the-containers-used-by-jobs)

The cleanup step still does run in the context of the runner's service account, but you can add elevation inside of the script if needed.

Another option is to include a sidecar container in the cleanup step and then run your custom container that cleans up. This container can be your own, and can run with 'root' access.

[An extra option could be to use this action from the marketplace as an extra step in the workflow](https://github.com/asilbek99/action-cleanup), as it will run inside of a container and cleanup. But this means the end-user has to include this in their workflow file. This docker image could also be used as the sidecar container in the cleanup step.

[The easiest option is adding the config for `ACTIONS_RUNNER_HOOK_JOB_COMPLETED` and execute the cleanup commands](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/running-scripts-before-or-after-a-job) (from a Docker container with root user).

Comment: Thanks for all the options!
The `container:` annotation from the 1st option doesn't work I guess since the job can run on a different runner. The linked action that can be used looks pretty similar to what I am creating right now since I thought that's the only option I can start a cleanup process in a container (with root) in a step. The last option looks interesting and I will check it. Thanks again!

Comment: The last option (last link) works. I'll add an answer to give more details on how it worked, but will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I add this answer to provide more details on the 3rd option @Rob Bos mentioned above.

I've added the following script to my self-hosted runner

```bash
cat /localdisk/github-action-scripts/cleanup.sh
#!/bin/sh
docker run --rm -i \
        -v $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/../../:/workspace \
        busybox:latest \
        /bin/sh -c "chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) /workspace"
```

then added the file `.env`

```bash
cat /localdisk/action-runner/.env
ACTIONS_RUNNER_HOOK_JOB_COMPLETED=/localdisk/github-action-scripts/cleanup.sh
```

followed by a

```bash
sudo systemctl restart actions.runner.*
```

and it works:

[image]